# iOS: UICollectionView sections from array with dates

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, date, collectionview

I have an `array` of `Person`. The Person object has many fields between them  `inscriptionDate` (a `timestamp`). I have to create a `collectionView` from this `array` but using `sections`. Every section has a header that is `inscriptionDate` as a date having this format `dd/mm/yyyy`. I have to sort the `array` by `inscriptionDate` but without time (only the format `dd/mm/yyyy`) in order to load the data in the `collectionView` (taking into consideration the sections). I have found from another question this [solution](https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch08p466collectionViewFlowLayout2/ch21p748collectionViewFlowLayout2/ViewController.swift). But how can I sort the `array` before doing this? How can I use this:

```
order = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().compareDate(now, toDate: olderDate, 
            toUnitGranularity: .Day)
```

in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to clean timestamp before the sorting. You can do that by using `Calendar` and `Date` extension:

```
extension Date {
    func noTime() -> Date! {
        let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: self)
        return Calendar.current.date(from: components)
    }
}
```

Then you'll just need to sort your array by date without time:

```
let sortedByDate = persons.sorted { $0.inscriptionDate.noTime() < $1.inscriptionDate.noTime() }
```

**Note.** Be careful with `compareDate` function of `Calendar`, since it comparing only specific component. If in this example: `NSCalendar.currentCalendar().compareDate(now, toDate: olderDate, toUnitGranularity: .Day)` you'll have same days in different months, the comparing result will show that dates are equal.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Your extension is so usefull !!

Comment: You can find different options on this site to say "Thank you" ;)

Comment: You're right! It's true that Jacobs's answer gives more informations about how to organise the data and how to use it in the collectionView but the base was your extension. So I'm going to thank you in a different way this time :)

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Vasilii Muravev, you will need to clean your `timestamp` object first, either using extensions or functions.  Timestamp isn't a valid Swift object btw, unless that is a custom class you created.

Then you can create a dictionary for your dataSource.  I will use @Vasilii Muravev's extension:

```
//var myKeys : [Date] = []
let sortedPeople = persons.sorted { $0.inscriptionDate.noTime() < $1.inscriptionDate.noTime() }
//break your array into a dictionary([Date : [Person]])
//personsSortedByDateInSections : [Date : [Person]] = [:]
for person in sortedPeople {
    if personsSortedByDateInSections[person.inscriptionDate] != nil {
        personsSortedByDateInSections[person.inscriptionDate]!.append(person)
    } else {
        personsSortedByDateInSections[person.inscriptionDate] = [person]
    }
}
myKeys = setKeyArray(personSortedByDateInSections.keys)
```

that will give you a dictionary object with all of your `Person` objects grouped(sectioned) by their `inscriptionDate`.  Then you will just need to fill out your collectionView delegate and datasource methods.

```
override func numberOfSections(in: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return myKeys.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return personsSortedByDateInSections[myKeys[section]].count
}
```

UPDATE:
As stated in your comment there is a issue with grabbing a array of the keys with swift dictionaries(I don't think swift dictionaries had this issue in earlier version?  I could be wrong)....anyway to workaround this I have used this function to set a class variable for the 'keyArray'.:

```
fileprivate func setKeysArray(_ keys: LazyMapCollection<Dictionary<Date, [Person]>, String) -> [Date]{
    var keysArray = [Date]()

    for key in keys {
        keysArray.append(key)
    }
    return keysArray
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a trouble in `numberOfItemsInSection`  I'm getting an error `Cannot subscript a value of type 'Dictionary<Date, [Person]>.Keys' with an index of type 'Int'`

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I didn't think about that when posting the answer.  You can create a function to grab a `keyArray`...I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `inscriptionDate` is a `Date`, why can't you sort on that? Since `Date` conforms to `Comparable` all you need is

```
let sortedByDate = persons.sorted { $0.inscriptionDate < $1.inscriptionDate }
```

Comment: it's timestamp and I want to compare it but without time

Comment: What exactly is "timestamp"? `TimeInterval`? And why would it hurt to use the time info in the sorting - two dates on the same day will be sorted together anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I wright a code for you I thing this code useful for you.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  sortData
//
//  Created by Bijender singh on 26/01/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Bijender singh. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let myDataArray = NSMutableArray()
        var myDataDic = NSMutableDictionary()

        myDataDic.setValue("Bijender", forKey: "name")
        myDataDic.setValue("1516965600", forKey: "date")
        myDataArray.add(myDataDic)

        myDataDic = NSMutableDictionary()
        myDataDic.setValue("ben", forKey: "name")
        myDataDic.setValue("1516965540", forKey: "date")
        myDataArray.add(myDataDic)

        myDataDic = NSMutableDictionary()
        myDataDic.setValue("Deke", forKey: "name")
        myDataDic.setValue("1516842180", forKey: "date")
        myDataArray.add(myDataDic)

        myDataDic = NSMutableDictionary()
        myDataDic.setValue("Veer", forKey: "name")
        myDataDic.setValue("1516842000", forKey: "date")
        myDataArray.add(myDataDic)

        myDataDic = NSMutableDictionary()
        myDataDic.setValue("Ashfaq", forKey: "name")
        myDataDic.setValue("1515981900", forKey: "date")
        myDataArray.add(myDataDic)


        print(myDataArray)

        let sortedArray = self.sortDataWithDate(arrayData: myDataArray)

        // sortedArray contane array which contan same date array 
        // you can use it according to you
        // sortedArray.count is total diffrent dates in your array
        // and (sortedArray.count[i] as! NSArray).count give you count of data of that date (0 < i < sortedArray.count)
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func sortDataWithDate(arrayData : NSArray) -> NSArray {
        //  var chat: [ChatMessage]!

        let returnArray = NSMutableArray()
        var subArray = NSMutableArray()
        let arrayDate = NSMutableArray()

        for i in 0 ..< arrayData.count {

            let msgDate = self.timeStampToDate(_timestamp: ((arrayData[i] as! NSDictionary).object(forKey: "date") as! String), _dateFormat: "dd/MM/yyyy")

            print("dddt \(msgDate)")

        //    print("date array \(arrayDate)  $$  msgDate \(msgDate)")
            if arrayDate.contains(msgDate) {

                subArray.add(arrayData[i])

            }
            else{
                arrayDate.add(msgDate)
                if arrayDate.count > 1 {
                    returnArray.add(subArray)
                }

                subArray = NSMutableArray()
                subArray.add(arrayData[i])
            }
        }

        if subArray != nil {
            returnArray.add(subArray)
        }

        print(returnArray)
        return returnArray
    }

     func timeStampToDate(_timestamp : String, _dateFormat : String) -> String{

        // _dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS"

        var date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(_timestamp)!)
        date += TimeInterval(Int(TimeZone.current.secondsFromGMT()) as NSNumber)
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT") //Set timezone that you want
        dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = _dateFormat
        let strDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        return strDate

    }

}
```

In this code I insert array as hard coded

```
(
        {
        date = 1516965600;
        name = Bijender;
    },
        {
        date = 1516965540;
        name = ben;
    },
        {
        date = 1516842180;
        name = Deke;
    },
        {
        date = 1516842000;
        name = Veer;
    },
        {
        date = 1515981900;
        name = Ashfaq;
    }
)
```

And out put array is

```
(
        (
                {
            date = 1516965600;
            name = Bijender;
        },
                {
            date = 1516965540;
            name = ben;
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            date = 1516842180;
            name = Deke;
        },
                {
            date = 1516842000;
            name = Veer;
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            date = 1515981900;
            name = Ashfaq;
        }
    )
)
```

Comment: This helps to make the header for table view also.